# как сделать два управляемых объектов в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я только начал изучать Unity  и столкнулся с проблемой: не получается управлять двумя объектами на сцене.
Сделал два перса с кодом для передвижения
У первого

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;                          // меня не забудь подключить, мы ж уровень перезагружать будем

public class doodletwo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static doodletwo instance;                          // это штучка нужна, чтобы мы могли использовать переменные в этом скрипте в других скриптах

    public float horizontalSpeed;
    float speedX;
    float horizontal;                                       // переменная для акселерометра
    public Rigidbody2D DoodleRigid;                         // публичный RB для дудлика

    void Start()
    {
        if (instance == null)                               // пишем эти строчки, чтоб можно было корректно использовать переменные в других скриптах
        {
            instance = this;
        }
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                speedX = -horizontalSpeed;
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                speedX = horizontalSpeed;
            }
            transform.Translate(speedX, 0, 0);
            speedX = 0;
        

        
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)       // столкновение объекта
    {
        if (collision.collider.name == "DeadZone")              // если дудлик сталкивается с объектом с именем "DeadZone"
        {

            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);                          // то уровень перезагружается
        }
    }


    // Подписывайся на канал ICE CREAM
    // Нашел неточность - напиши мне на почту или в комменты! Пасибос)
}
```

У второго

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;                          // меня не забудь подключить, мы ж уровень перезагружать будем

public class Doodle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Doodle instance;                          // это штучка нужна, чтобы мы могли использовать переменные в этом скрипте в других скриптах

    public float horizontalSpeed;
    float speedX;
    float horizontal;                                       // переменная для акселерометра
    public Rigidbody2D DoodleRigid;                         // публичный RB для дудлика

    void Start()
    {
        if (instance == null)                               // пишем эти строчки, чтоб можно было корректно использовать переменные в других скриптах
        {
            instance = this;
        }
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
        
            
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                speedX = -horizontalSpeed;
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.B))
            {
                speedX = horizontalSpeed;
            }
            transform.Translate(speedX, 0, 0);
            speedX = 0;
       
        
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)       // столкновение объекта
    {
        if (collision.collider.name == "DeadZone")              // если дудлик сталкивается с объектом с именем "DeadZone"
        {
            
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);                          // то уровень перезагружается
        }
    }
   

    // Подписывайся на канал ICE CREAM
    // Нашел неточность - напиши мне на почту или в комменты! Пасибос)
}
```

По отдельности они оба передвигаются, а когда двое на сцене то только один.
Помогите с кодом, может кто- то знает как это сделать.

Comment: у тебя ошибка с классом doodletwo не вылезает?

Comment: Проверяй инпуты в `Update()` . `FixedUpdate()` используется для физического передвижения

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте что на объектах заданы значения скорости в инспекторе
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня работает все

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class doodletwo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static doodletwo
        instance; // это штучка нужна, чтобы мы могли использовать переменные в этом скрипте в других скриптах

    public float horizontalSpeed;
    float speedX;
    float horizontal; // переменная для акселерометра
    public Rigidbody2D DoodleRigid; // публичный RB для дудлика

    void Start()
    {
        if (instance == null) // пишем эти строчки, чтоб можно было корректно использовать переменные в других скриптах
        {
            instance = this;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            speedX = -horizontalSpeed;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            speedX = horizontalSpeed;
        }

        transform.Translate(speedX, 0, 0);
        speedX = 0;
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) // столкновение объекта
    {
        if (collision.collider.name == "DeadZone") // если дудлик сталкивается с объектом с именем "DeadZone"
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);                          // то уровень перезагружается
        }
    }
}
```

--

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Doodle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Doodle instance;                          // это штучка нужна, чтобы мы могли использовать переменные в этом скрипте в других скриптах

    public float horizontalSpeed;
    float speedX;
    float horizontal;                                       // переменная для акселерометра
    public Rigidbody2D DoodleRigid;                         // публичный RB для дудлика

    void Start()
    {
        if (instance == null)                               // пишем эти строчки, чтоб можно было корректно использовать переменные в других скриптах
        {
            instance = this;
        }
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            speedX = -horizontalSpeed;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.B))
        {
            speedX = horizontalSpeed;
        }
        transform.Translate(speedX, 0, 0);
        speedX = 0;
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)       // столкновение объекта
    {
        if (collision.collider.name == "DeadZone")              // если дудлик сталкивается с объектом с именем "DeadZone"
        {
            
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);                          // то уровень перезагружается
        }
    }

}
```